# How to prevent collapsing of Expander listitem when refresh List with new DataContext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a List of Expanders in WPF. The List is bounded to an array of objects, and I need to update them periodically.

When I update an array of objects by reading them from DB after I expanded one of Expanders in List, the Expander automatically collapse.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Edit 1

This is the part of xml of ObjectTab,

```
<ListView x:Name="list" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ObjectRealtimeControl></local:ObjectRealtimeControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the code of ObjectTab is

```
public partial class ObjectTab : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SomeObject[] Objects { get; set; }

    public ObjectTab ()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        runWorker();
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private void runWorker()
    {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        while (!worker.CancellationPending )
        {
            refreshAll();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void refreshAll()
    {

        Shared.DB.read("Some SQL", (ex, dataTable) =>
        {
            Objects = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select((row)=>{
                    return new SomeObject() {
                        id = row[0].toString(),
                    };
            }).ToArray();
            OnPropertyChanged("Objects");
        }
    }
}
```

ObjectRealtimeControl contains Expander, other controls to represent SomeObject class.

Comment: Does `myExpander.IsExpanded = true;` not work?

Comment: @Smartis I think it works, but then I have to keep the expanded Expanders. I want to keep code short because I don't have much time for that. Also objects may be deleted or added or updated in DB, so an array of objects can be changed dynamically. So I can track them and update my List manually, but I'm worrying that it is to time-waste works..

Comment: You haven't provided any code that demonstrates how and where the expanders "automatically collapse". You are obviously doing something that causes them to collapse. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 okay.. this is my code, and after first reading from DB, List shows list items which is Expander. I expand one of the list item, but BackgroundWorker keep reading from DB and updates Objects property. After Objects property have been updated, all Expanders in List collapsed.

Comment: @Chickenchaser: So you are simply updating the ids of the existing objects? Where is the markup where the converted is defined?

Comment: @mm8 okay imsorry. I update the whole object. And SomeSql is read all rows in table. ObjectRealtimeControl has Expander as top child control, and it has several child controls.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue so it's hard to say anything about your expanders but instead of raising the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Objects` property itself, you could try to update the individual properties of each object or clear the same collection and re-populare it. Something like this:

```
public partial class ObjectTab : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> Objects { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();

    public ObjectTab()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        runWorker();
    }

    ...

    private void refreshAll()
    {

        Shared.DB.read("Some SQL", (ex, dataTable) =>
        {
            var newObjects = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select((row) => {
                return new SomeObject()
                {
                    id = row[0].toString(),
                };
            }).ToArray();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                Objects.Clear();
                foreach (var newObject in newObjects)
                    Objects.Add(newObject);
            }));
        };
    }
}
```